# Change Sort Order of Edit Action Customer Grid Column

Tags: magento2, grid, customer-grid, custom-column-grid

I want to move edit action column beside customer name programmatically in customer grid like this:

[image]

how to do it from custom module?

i've tried this, but still not working

**app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_listing.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_columns">
        <actionsColumn name="actions">
          <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
              <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                  <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
              </item>
          </argument>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

**and i change the content with this, but still not working**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd"> 
    <columns name="customer_columns"> 
        <actionsColumn name="actions" class="Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\Actions" sortOrder="2">
            <settings>
                <indexField>entity_id</indexField>
            </settings>
        </actionsColumn>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

i already delete the customer_listing in ui_bookmark table, clean+flush cache, run setup:upgrade & di:compile, but still not working

Comment: empty ui_bookmark table and check

Comment: https://www.magestore.com/magento-2-tutorial/ui-bookmark-component/

Comment: @JugalKishor still not working

Comment: please override correct and clear ui_bookmark table and refresh cache

Comment: @JugalKishor still not working, have u seen my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `sortOrder` option is applicable to the Action column.

The Action column uses `ActionsColumn` ui component that has a configuration option called `draggable`, which is defaulted to `false`. You can extend its js script `app/code/Magento/Ui/view/base/web/js/grid/columns/actions.js` and set `draggable` to `true`. This will enable the column to be dragged to any position you want. More info can be found in [devDocs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/components/ui-actionscolumn.html)

In your case, first create a `requirejs-config.js` under `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/` with the below code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions': 'Namespace_Module/js/actions',
            uiGridColumnsActions: 'Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/actions'
        }
    }
};
```

Then create a custom js file `actions.js` under `app/code/Namespace/Module/view/adminhtml/web/js/` with the below code to set `draggable` to `true`:

```
define([
    "jquery",
    'uiGridColumnsActions'
], function($, actions){
    'use strict';

    //make it draggable on customer listing page only
    if($( 'body' ).hasClass( 'customer-index-index' )){
        return actions.extend({
            defaults: {
                draggable: true
            }
        });
    }else{
        return actions;
    }
});
```

Clear static files and cache afterwards.

Comment: how to do it from custom module and only set true for customer_listing grid ?

Comment: answer updated with sample code.

Comment: Work perfectly in 2.3.3

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

very easy, in the function  _prepareColumns of the grid.
Move the code that add "Action" column beside the code that add "Name" column
Example:

```
$this->addColumn(
            'Name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );

  $this->addColumn(
            'edit',
           [
            'header' => __('Edit'),
            'type' => 'action'
            ..............
           ]
        );
```

Comment: i believe this is for Magento 1, because Magento 2 customer grid is using xml layout

Comment: @TinyDancer Magento 2 is available this action, when you add grid using Block Template extend **Widget\Grid\Extended**